# How to move an object to a group using python?

Tags: python, collections

I have a script that creates a group hierarchy. In this hierarchy it is necessary to decompose links. All I managed to do was find this command: `obj = bpy.context.active_object`

`bpy.data.collections['tube'].objects.link(obj)`
it makes the object dependent on the collection but does not completely transfer my object.

[image]

Comment: You need to unlink it from the original collection

Comment: There's no such thing as "completely transferred" because an object can be part of multiple collections. In your case the object "_tube" is part of the "space" and "tube" collection. If you want to remove it from the "space" collection you can use `bpy.data.collections['space'].objects.unlink(obj)`